# VBA check if whole row of multidimensional variant is empty without loops

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variant

**Is there a quick way to check whether a whole row of a variant is empty?**

My multi-dimensional array / variant has n-rows and m-columns.

**The only way I can think of is to loop through the columns (of a specific row) and use the IsEmpty() function to determine if a cell is empty.**

The variant only consists strings.

**Do you know a faster way? Maybe something like this pseudo-code: `IsEmpty(myarr(1,*))`**

this pseudocode would mean to check the all columns of the first row if they are empty.

Comment: A dirty way would be to have a hidden column on your sheet with all elements in the row concatenated, then copy the formula down.  In theory, that column would have an empty value if there were no cells with values.  All you need to do then, is include the column in your variant array.  It's a bit dirty, but would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
Sub Test()

Dim myarr() As Variant, indx As Long

myarr = Range("A8:C20").Value 'Or however you initialize your array.
indx = 1 'Or whichever row you would want to check.

With Application
    Debug.Print Join(.Index(myarr, indx, 0), "") <> ""
End With

End Sub
```

Not sure if it will be faster than a loop though, since we call a worksheet application.

Comment: Nice! Voted up. Placing it in a function `arrEmptyRow(arr, iRow as Long) as Boolean` maybe will be more spectacular...:)

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a faster way especially considering that arrays in VBA are stored column-wise in memory. The values on a single row are not stored adjacent in memory as it's the case with column values - you could easily test this by running a `For Each` loop on an array.

That being said, you should probably consider having a `Function` that checks if a specific row is empty so that you can call it repeatedly and maybe also check for null strings if needed. For example a range of formulas returning "" will not be empty but you might want to have the ability to consider them empty.

For example, you could use something like this:

```
Public Function Is2DArrayRowEmpty(ByRef arr As Variant _
                                , ByVal rowIndex As Long _
                                , Optional ByVal ignoreEmptyStrings As Boolean = False _
) As Boolean
    Const methodName As String = "Is2DArrayRowEmpty"
    '
    If GetArrayDimsCount(arr) <> 2 Then
        Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Array is not two-dimensional"
    ElseIf rowIndex < LBound(arr, 1) Or rowIndex > UBound(arr, 1) Then
        Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Row Index out of bounds"
    End If
    '
    Dim j As Long
    Dim v As Variant
    '
    For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        v = arr(rowIndex, j)
        Select Case VBA.VarType(v)
        Case VbVarType.vbEmpty
            'Continue to next element
        Case VbVarType.vbString
            If Not ignoreEmptyStrings Then Exit Function
            If LenB(v) > 0 Then Exit Function
        Case Else
            Exit Function
        End Select
    Next j
    '
    Is2DArrayRowEmpty = True 'If code reached this line then row is Empty
End Function

Public Function GetArrayDimsCount(ByRef arr As Variant) As Long
    If Not IsArray(arr) Then Exit Function
    '
    Const MAX_DIMENSION As Long = 60
    Dim dimension As Long
    Dim tempBound As Long
    '
    'A zero-length array has 1 dimension! Ex. Array() returns (0 to -1)
    On Error GoTo FinalDimension
    For dimension = 1 To MAX_DIMENSION
        tempBound = LBound(arr, dimension)
    Next dimension
Exit Function
FinalDimension:
    GetArrayDimsCount = dimension - 1
End Function
```

Notice that I haven't checked for `IsObject` as your values are coming from a range in Excel but you would normally check for that in a general case.

Your pseudocode `IsEmpty(myarr(1,*))` could be translated to:

```
Is2DArrayRowEmpty(myarr, 1, False) 'Empty strings would not be considered Empty
```

or

```
Is2DArrayRowEmpty(myarr, 1, True) 'Empty strings would be considered Empty
```

Comment: Did you try the below posted answer? It shows that it is possible. In a fast, compact way, I would say...

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes. My solution is about 3-5 times faster. I admit the use of worksheet functions is more compact but my solution would work in any host application not just Excel.

Comment: @FaneDuru Actually, my solution can be hundreds/thousands of times faster depending on the array size. For example for range 1:1000 (all columns), my solution executes in 4 milliseconds and the other posted answer in about 3 seconds.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I just sticked to For-Loops as they are way faster than the mentioned Joins. But to be honest, the other solution answers my question best - though it is much slower.

Comment: I can agree, the code is faster. I took "a quick way" and without "loop through the column" has been answered with that compact code. Otherwise, using a simple iteration by columns, `If arr(rowIndex, i) <> "" Then rowIsEmpty = False: Exit Function`, will do the job as fast as your code, even a little faster, not testing more conditions. All function code lines number should be 4, plus one for the iteration variable declaration, I think... Anyhow, placing in an array a cell formula value returning an empty string and an empty cell value, both of them will return the same using `arr(i, j) = ""`.